# Mi grafica dentro del reporte en Cristal Reports no se ve,

Tags: crystal-reports, reportviewer, reportviewerreporte

Hice mi reporte en Crystal, cuano lo previsualizo en mi maquina, todo se ve bien, la grafica se ve completa, pero cuando lo subo a mi BD me marca el espacio en blanco y cuando doy click donde deberia verse mi grafica dice: drilled onan area that doesnot have detail data, to drill down, please click on an area that has data.
Lo curioso es que en la previsualizacion cuando lo estoy elaborando funciona perfecto, me trae todos los datos y en la BD solo me trae los datos pero sin grafico, alguien que ya le haya pasado y me pueda apoyzr a solucionarlo,